# The layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" could not be found

Tags: web-development, asp.net-mvc

I got this error and I can't figure out what is going on. I am positive the _layout.cshtml resides in the shared folder and for the sake of trying things out, I moved to the Home folder and it then told that the Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml couldn't be found there either. So now I'm thinking the problem is in the call for this file for some reason.

I'm not going to pretend I know ASP.NET MVC4, so please when you answer, explain it as you would to someone who is not familiar with the system at all. Believe it or not, this error came from tutorial #1 ha ha

Here's the code to show that I did code it right:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

And here is a picture of the location

[image]

p.s. I did my research, Google has nothing and there is another question here but it was asked on 2008 with MVC3 which is completely different

I am running ASP.NET MVC4 on Azure

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you rename your project you can get that error. Solution is simple. Just remove tilda (~) -> /View/.... instead of ~/View..., also in your _Layout file remove tilda from all links

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested or had the same problem. It seems this may be a problem with the server (hence, why it runs fine in localhost) :) But anyway, if it happens to you, do this:

1. duplicate the layout and rename it Layout2
2. change its call in the ViewStart.cshtml so the right layout is called per page
3. Go to Azure or whoever is your server and delete everything.
4. recreate your directory
5. Go back to VS and clean, build, and publish

And you should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

Search for '_Layout.cshtml' in Solution Explorer (righthand side). Then you will find _Layout.cshtml. Right click on the file and click 'Scope to This'.

Voila! All your missing files will be visible under 'Shared' folder. Dont know why exactly this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Try this:

```
@{ 
   Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: Please use [code formatting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), otherwise it won't be displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the file from your project and re-create it. If you check your project folder you'll see there is no Layout file there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this and are certain the file is in the proper location, try deleting everything from the web server and redeploying.

My scenario:

- Using WebDeploy
- Had removed the "_Layout.cshtml" file from the project since the previous deployment; after deployment the code didn't work, realized my mistake, so added it back in, and redeployed - but it did not solve the problem.
- Had no problem in development environment

Answer (score -1):

In **Solution Explorer**, right click on the *Shared folder*, then *Publish Shared*.